# how to Install glibc 2.3.2 on Gentoo?

Tags: glibc, libc, gentoo

I'm wrote an application and I need to execute it on Gentoo,
but when I try run it, I get the following message:

/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.3.4' not found (required by /usr/local/myapp/lib/myapplib.so.1)

the current GLIBC version in this gentoo is 2.3.2.

I can't update this glibc, because I don't have permission, so I need to 'downgrade'
my glibc to the same version (2.3.2) ... how can I do it?

tks,

Comment: You can do it either manually or by using your distro's package manager. I recommend you don't. See answer from mattst88.

Answer (score 1):

The "/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.3.4' not found" problem comes from trying to run a binary compiled against a newer glibc on a system with an old version of glibc. Downgrading glibc is *strongly* discouraged for this reason.

Since you say you wrote the application, it seems to me that the simplest solution is to recompile the application on the system where you plan to run it.

Comment: This is the correct answer (hi matt!).  It looks like you compiled the binary on another system against that system's newer glibc, and then tried to run it on a Gentoo box that has a lesser version of glibc.  You can get away with this on some binary distros as long as they stay within the same glibc revision.  But you will find it really hard to move to completely different distros, especially one like Gentoo in which every system is literally unique, without a recompile of the source.  If you built your Makefile properly, just re-run `configure` and then `make` and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually wrestling with the same issue, so maybe I have some information that can help.

In short, your binary was compiled to look for libc.so.6. GLIBC_2.3.4 is in libc.so.5. As far as I know, if you downgrade your glibc on your dev machine some of your other programs may not work properly (because they were compiled to look for the current version). Somehow CentOS/RHEL have a compat-glibc package that can live along side of a current glibc without causing this error. If your dev box uses CentOS/RHEL, install that package/recompile and you should be good to go. You may need to use an older compiler for it to look for the older library. If you're not developing on CentOS/RHEL, continue on.

My plan of attack today is to compile glibc from source. This means using a compiler that was released around the same time as the older version of glibc. You may run into some stumbling blocks (such as needing an older version of buildutils, etc.), but my hope is once the libc.so.5 is compiled and installed into /usr/local/lib my application will find that before it finds libc.so.6 in /lib.

So there it is. It's not for the faint of heart, and it's definitely not a quick solution. Today I plan on testing this out, so I can't really say it's the right solution. Please, hivemind.. if I'm flat-out wrong correct me and save this poor soul from this winding torturous road :-)

EDIT: [link to glibc sources](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/)